# Simplify and Evaluate function of X

Tags: functions

I am having problems understanding the answer to this question

Let $f(x) = 1 - x + 4x^2 $  Evaluate $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$

Any help would be much appreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The answer is in the question. If $$f(x) = 1 - x + 4x^2$$then $$f(x+h) = 1 - (x+h) + 4(x+h)^2$$ Expand the second one; from the result substract the first and divide the result by $h$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{1-(x+h)+4(x+h)^2-(1-x+4x^2)}{h}\\=\frac{1-x-h+4(x^2+2hx+h^2)-1+x-4x^2}{h}\\=\frac{-h+4x^2-4x^2+8hx+4h^2}{h}\\=\frac{-h+8hx+4h^2}{h}\\\frac{h(-1+8x+4h)}{h}=-1+8x+4h :)$$